# How can I cut out a shape if it goes outside of a canvas with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to create a circle and cut out a part of it if it goes outside another shape.

For example, if half of the circle goes outside a square, cut out everything on the outside but not on the inside. Something like this snippet, except the part outside the square is hidden. I prefer to avoid masking it since this will go on top of another canvas, which covers the whole screen.

**Code**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,100,100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(70, 90, 60, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `clip()` the circle, like so;

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,100,100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();  // clip circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(70, 90, 60, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that was simple.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the dimensions I've adjusted for cropping the outside part of sqaure

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,100,100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(70, 90, 60, 10, -4*Math.PI * .05 , false)
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```